# Guid format is not Recognised

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I get this error in my `DropDownList` when it's converting the string to guid.

> Stack Trace:
>   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException) at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result) at System.Guid..ctor(String g) at Projects_AddProject.wizCreateProject_ActiveStepChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnActiveStepChanged(Object source, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.MultiViewActiveViewChanged(Object source, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.MultiView.OnActiveViewChanged(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.MultiView.set_ActiveViewIndex(Int32 value) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.set_ActiveStepIndex(Int32 value) at Projects_AddProject.proxy_Navigate(Object sender, HistoryEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RaiseNavigate(HistoryEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.LoadHistoryState(String serverState) at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

The method is wizCreateProject_ActiveStepChanged. Simply I need to know how to fix this conversion.

Here is method where we get error:

```
protected void wizCreateProject_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (wizCreateProject.ActiveStepIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            if (rbFrmTemp.Checked)
            {
                int tenantID = TenantUtils.getTenantId(Page);
                EzProject templateProject = DBAccessProjects.GetProject(tenantID, new Guid(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue));
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I get error in this line:

```
EzProject templateProject = DBAccessProjects.GetProject(tenantID, new Guid(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue));
```

I checked that ddlProjectTemplates have this type of vaues

```xml
<option value="7590aab2-29b9-4262-9982-4403ca7b52f2">Managed Services Agreement</option>
```

Is this correct Guid format. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the content of `ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue` while you're creating a new guid (new Guid())

Comment: It is probably an empty string that is failing to parse.

Comment: @leppie yes first value of dropdown is empty...here is the strucure of datadisplay in dropdown...                                <option value=" "></option>
<option value="72cb9ff3-8591-4b5b-bc61-a6812e160b7d">Break/Fix</option>

Comment: I tried  var id = Guid.Parse("7590aab2-29b9-4262-9982-4403ca7b52f2"); and it worked fine . so make sure that the SelectedValue has really a value

Comment: @DanHunex  first value of dropdown is empty..i think thats the reason.   <option value=" "></option>
<option value="72cb9ff3-8591-4b5b-bc61-a6812e160b7d">Break/Fix</option>..check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is your drop down list selection is being trashed when you post back and it is picking the first thing in the drop down list, which is empty and then your GUID conversion fails. Protect your GUID conversion to only have it applied to values that are not null or not empty, like this:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue))
{
    // Now you know there is some value to attempt to convert
    EzProject templateProject = DBAccessProjects.GetProject(tenantID, new Guid(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue));
}
```

For even greater protection, use the `Guid.TryParse()` method instead of the `Guid` constructor, like this:

```
Guid newGuid;
if (Guid.TryParse(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue, out newGuid))
{
    EzProject templateProject = DBAccessProjects.GetProject(tenantID, newGuid);
}
```

Comment: instead of this I would use 
Guid.TryParse(string input,out Guid result) which returns boolean that shows success or failure

Comment: @KarlAnderson  error is due to empty string at first position....<option value=" "></option>???

Comment: @monika - where is the logic that binds the values to the drop down list?

Comment: @KarlAnderson this method used to bind dropdown.. public static void SetProjectTemplatesDropDown(int tenantID, int loggedInMasterID, DropDownList ddlProjTemplates,bool addBlank)
    {
vEZProject[] tempProjects =DBAccessProjects.GetTemplateProjectsForDropDown(tenantID, loggedInMasterID);
        DevClass.addBlank(ddlProjTemplates,addBlank);
        if (tempProjects != null)
        {
         foreach (vEZProject p in tempProjects)
            {
                ddlProjTemplates.Items.Add(new ListItem(p.ProjectName, p.ProjectID.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @monika - did you try the `Guid.TryParse()` syntax at the end of my answer? That should account for any format that does not parse to a `Guid`. On a side note, are there any `ProjectName` returned from the database that contain just a space?

Comment: @KarlAnderson  first value of dropdown is empty...i think thats the problem....yes i think Guid.Tryparse will  work

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use

```
  var id = Guid.Parse("7590aab2-29b9-4262-9982-4403ca7b52f2");
```

and it worked perfect.So the culprit is the ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue and make sure it has value.

Use the following

```
Guid result;

if(Guid.TryParse(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue ,out result)
{
   ///do your stuff here

}
```

Comment: First value of  ddlProjTemplates  is empty..  like this...<option value=" "></option>.....I think thats the reason of erro.

Comment: @ErikNoren is this due to this  <option value=" "></option>??  right?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: call

```
    EzProject templateProject = DBAccessProjects.GetProject(tenantID, new Guid(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```

where you are calling

```
    EzProject templateProject = DBAccessProjects.GetProject(tenantID, new Guid(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue));
```

as new Guid(String) is a valid method, but new Guid(Object) is not.

Comment: `SelectedValue` is a string already, no need to call `ToString()` on it. Read [ListControl.SelectedValue Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx).

Comment: You are right, rookie mistake on my part. I came to this from Silverlight mindset.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you are doing it at a post back or not , on `Page_Load` check

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{

}
```

then check your selected value for `null`

```
if(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue != null && ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue.Length > 0)
{

}
```